# How to add mage_captcha on newsletter form in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, captcha

I just want to know how can I add captcha on **mage_newsletter** on each page of site. Here my **.xml** code block for view **captcha**

```
  <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
        <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
            <reference name="head">
                <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
            </reference>
            <action method="setFormId"><formId>contacts</formId></action>
            <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
            <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
        </block>
    </block>
```

Comment: use google captcha

Comment: please explain how can i use is there any extension available for it or any other source

Comment: Magento captcha is not good and it looks very odd. i am suggested to use google captcha and it is easy to implement it. check below link for that:- https://www.codexworld.com/new-google-recaptcha-with-php/

Comment: customize this https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and I made it solved one extension "Google Invisible reCaptcha"

Wait... I changed few modifications in JS code also.

After installing extension set Site key and secret in admin side and open subscription.phtml

YOUR-PROJECT/app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml

Add code just after Form Tag.

```
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="YOUR-SITE-KEY"></div>
```

In the last of file add this JS Snippet.

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#recaptcha_response_field').addClass('required-captcha-entry');
    })
    var yourFormValidationObj = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-details');

    Validation.add('required-captcha-entry', ' ', function(v) {
        return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v);
    })
</script>
```

It worked for me. Cheers if it works for you..

Comment: Could you expand on the one extension "Google Invisible reCaptcha".

Comment: Does this extension work on localhost?

Comment: Yes @aravind, it works. In case if you would like to run Captcha in Localhost you need to pass http://localhost/ in the trusted URL under Google Developer Account.


1. Go to your [google reCaptcha admin panel](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin)
2. Add localhost & 127.0.0.1 to domains of a new site like the [following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikMHd.jpg)

Comment: @Nidhishanker Modi  Ok let me try this solution..

Comment: Yes, Let me know if it is not working for you @aravind

Comment: I used the above script and got the reCaptcha in my form. But the form captcha validation is not working. @NidhishankerModi can you please help on this?

Comment: @MagentoUser

I have added validation in my js code.
Validation.add('required-captcha-entry', ' ', function(v) {
        return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v);
    })

Make sure there are not two different google captcha forms on same form.